# install java se 6 on a mac without software updater

Tags: java, macos, unix

hello guys i've come from a very long issue where i was obliged to remove the /System/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0 and the 1.6. now i downloaded the JavaForMacOSX10.5Update1, because it's not available anymore on the software updater, and run it.Now i can't find it in /System/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/ where i'm expecting it.where should i find it? thanks i need for running various projects thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you manually have removed it, the software update system does not know that it is gone.

I would suggest doing a Time Machine backup, reinstall the machine from the isntallation media, and restore the Time Machine backup.  This should repair everything, but might take a while.

Comment: The moral of the story: never remove or modify anything from /System/Library unless you are prepared to reload the startup partition.